# Why I can't get incremented var outside loop on shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts

I'm using this script to make a counter, and I want to access it outside the inner loop, but I'm having no luck. What am I missing?

```
while [ 1 ] 
do
        COUNTER=0
        ls /tmp/paping* | grep -v pid | while read pap
        do
                ret=`cat $pap`
                if [ "a$ret" == "aTimeout" ]
                then
                        echo "Do something"
                else
                        arr[$COUNTER]=$pap
                        COUNTER=$(( COUNTER + 1 ))
                fi
                sleep 0.3
                echo $COUNTER
        done
#THIS LINE RETURNs 0
        echo $COUNTER
done
```

Comment: Nope, the inner echo outputs me the right value. But when the inner loop ends COUNTER is 0. I don't know why

Comment: See [Does while spawn a subshell in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204597/does-while-spawn-a-subshell-in-bash?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This is gold @steeldriver. Thanks. I assumed that something like that was happening, but I didn't know it was called subshell. I believe this is my problem.

Comment: Also, [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs): `for pap in /tmp/paping*; do [[ $pap == *pid* ]] && continue; ...; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @steeldriver pointed me, when I pipe I create a subshell and the var values are not passed to the outer var.

As this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204597/does-while-spawn-a-subshell-in-bash?noredirect=1&lq=1) provides

The solution would be something like this:

```
while [ 1 ] 
do
        COUNTER=0
 while read pap
        do
                ret=`cat $pap`
                if [ "a$ret" == "aTimeout" ]
                then
                        echo "do something"
                else
                        arr[$COUNTER]=$pap
                        COUNTER=$(( COUNTER + 1 ))
                fi
                sleep 0.3
                echo $COUNTER
        done < <( ls /tmp/paping* | grep -v pid)
        echo $COUNTER
done
```

Now my counter is working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your shell is `bash`, placing the command `shopt -s lastpipe` at the top of your script is one possible solution.